# Parallelogram TextView in Android

Tags: android, canvas, textview

I'm trying to create a parallelogram-shaped textview with some text inside (which has to be dynamic, based on some results retrieved from server). Up to now I extended TextView class implementing `draw(Canvas canvas)` method, I turned out into drawing the shape, but when I add my textView in xml and I try to add some text, the text simpy does not appear.

Here is my custom view:

```
public class ParallelogramTextView extends TextView {

   Paint mInnerPaint;

   public ParallelogramTextView(Context context) {
       super(context);
       init();
   }

   public ParallelogramTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
       super(context, attrs, defStyle);
       init();
   }

   public ParallelogramTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
       super(context, attrs);
       init();
   }


   private void init() {
       mInnerPaint = new Paint();
       mInnerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
       mInnerPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
       mInnerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       mInnerPaint.setTextSize(20f);
   }


   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
       super.draw(canvas);
       Path path = new Path();
       path.moveTo(getWidth(),0);
       path.lineTo(getWidth()/10, 0);
       path.lineTo(0, getHeight());
       path.lineTo(getWidth() - (getWidth()/10),getHeight());
       path.lineTo(getWidth(), 0);
       canvas.drawPath(path, mInnerPaint);
   }
}
```

And here my xml:

```
<ParallelogramTextView
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Test"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:id="@+id/parallelogramTextView" />
```

I don't understand why text is not showing. Someone can help me? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

I found a solution changing completely approach, I created a drawable representing a **parallelogram shape** using **Vector** and I used it as background for a normal `TextView`. 
Don't know if it is best practice, but it worked for me.

Here the code of the drawable:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:width="200dp"
  android:height="50dp"
  android:viewportWidth="200"
  android:viewportHeight="50">

  <path android:fillColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
      android:pathData="M 200 0 L 20 0 L 0 50 L 180 50 L 200 0" />

</vector>
```